# using JavaScript from another page

Tags: javascript, html

I found the following Javascript effect to be interesting and wanted to use it on my webpage as background.

http://www.chiptune.com/starfield/starfield.html

I saved the html page on to my computer and tried to run it locally, but all it render is a blank black page.

The page doesn't seem to use any external files other than the adsense .js'es.
Then why is running on my browse directly from the their website but not locally from my computer.

Note - I ran it as file:///home/anirudh/fest/stars/Starfield.html and not from local server. Is that why it is not running?

Comment: Which browser did you save it with? What does the error console show?

Comment: including html page does not include the whole includes of that document, it just saves the HTML

Comment: It's not working because their server 'serves' up the javascript and other assets. If you open that local page up in firebug or the chrome inspector I bet you see a ton of errors for missing assets.

Comment: Im sorry, I do not what  error console is.

Comment: Right Click ==> Inspect Element ==> Click Console (if using chrome)

Comment: Oh. does that mean I cannot use it? @ryan

Comment: @AspiringAqib @AndrewHall `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

Comment: You shouldn't put your `<script>` tags _in between_ your `</head>` and `<body>`

Comment: I am recommending you to not to use that effect because it bottlenecked my lappy

Comment: @lan but its working fine when I run it directly

Comment: @Anirudh It probably works in newer browsers that "fix" it. But the only 2 elements that should be children of `<html>` are `<head>` and `<body>`. I would love to see what happens in IE. I don't know, maybe it's fine. But the script tags shouldn't be next to head or body

Comment: @Anirudh I get blank black screens when I try to open it in IE 7 and IE 8. Just saying.

Comment: @lan that is not the problem bcoz it should also show error there at original document. He cloned the document buddy :D

Comment: @AspiringAqib When did I say it was the problem? All I was doing was pointing out the validity of the HTML

Comment: @AspiringAqib And as I already said, it happens on older browsers that can't handle/fix invalid things without bugging out. So while the newer browsers that we test it with work, it doesn't mean it's right. I was just pointing out something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the 2 adsense js files are missing when you run locally, the rest of the javascript does not execute.

Removing references to the 2 js files fixes the issue as tested just now by me :)

Comment: yeah? I did try it. Let me see it again.

Comment: Well i just removed the 2 js files and the call to urchin then it worked - no errors in console and the screen displayed properly

Comment: There are some references to adsense in the middle of the rest of the code... Starts with `var adsense=$i('adsense');`. If you don't remove that too, it doesn't work.